# Xcode project won't display std::string in debugger anymore

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

I have an Xcode project that will not display C++ std::strings when I am debugging. It's incredibly frustrating because I am having to resort to print statements or outputting each character one at a time in the LLDB console window, which is time consuming and hard to read.

Every other person using this same project is having the same problem, and other projects are not seeing this problem, so I would think that this is a project setting of some kind. I'm in debug and there are no optimizations turned on, so I've eliminated that as the issue. I've also compared project settings between working projects and the one with this problem and they appear identical in every way that they can be.

Here's a sample of the output I get, `*_M_p` in this example is correct, the first character of the string is a question mark:

[image]

And here's what I get in the debug console if I inspect the string one character at a time:

[image]

I've heard that switching back to GDB from LLVM might solve the problem, but GDB gave me other issues with debugging certain data types, so I'll just have new problems in that case.

Comment: Did you try `print map_environment.c_str()` ?

Comment: That worked! That helps quite a bit, but I'd really like to get the watch window to show me the strings. Thanks!

Comment: Then all you need to do is to force watch window to show you string.c_str() instead of string.

Comment: It seems to be intermittent, after trying this a couple more times on later runs of the program, on the same variable, it won't print it anymore. Now I get this output when I use the `print` command:
`(const char *) $0 = 0xec33ffec`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My co-worker figured out the fix for this: Turn off the Guard Malloc option in the scheme settings.

- Click the scheme that is exhibiting the problem
- Click on Edit Scheme
- Click on Diagnostics
- Uncheck the 'Enable Guard Malloc' option.

Now std::strings should be showing up. We don't know why this is the case, it may be a bug in Xcode, but I would think it would've been spotted awhile ago. Also, this was tested on multiple projects and enabling Guard Malloc always causes std::strings to not show up properly in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try this lldb command

```
exp -f s -- myString
```

You are telling the lldb to show the expression of your string with the format c String

Answer (score 0):

This might not have caused the original poster's problem, but it caused mine: I was using Xcode 6.4 while most of the code had been built with 6.2. Switching to 6.2 made the values visible in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

po string_name